# Cannot upload files and folders in directory via FTP in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I have a few folders I wish to upload to a server via FTP.

This is the folder structure:

```
build >
    fonts >
        - font1.ttf
        - font2.ttf
    images >
        - img1.png
        - img2.png
    javascripts >
        - script.js
    stylesheets >
        - style.css
    index.html
```

I have `fileup.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo user USERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
echo PASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat
echo prompt>> ftpcmd.dat

echo cd %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd %2>>ftpcmd.dat
echo mput *.*>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 123.456.78.9
del ftpcmd.dat
pause
```

And `run_ftp.bat` which is a single line, `public_html/` is the destination of the files on the server and `C:\Web\build` is where the files are located on my PC:

```
fileup public_html/ C:\Web\build
```

The `run_ftp.bat` is located in C:\Web and `fileup.bat` is in C:\Windows so it appears in the PATH and I can run fileup in cmd.

When I run `run_ftp.bat` the only files that get uploaded to the server are in the root of /build, so only index.html is uploaded. The console logs: `Error opening local file fonts.` for each of the folders inside /build.

Here's the log:

```
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp> prompt
Interactive mode Off .
ftp> cd public_html/
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
ftp> lcd C:\Web\build
Local directory now C:\Web\build.
ftp> mput *.*
Error opening local file fonts.
Error opening local file images.
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 57128
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.142 seconds (measured here), 1.78 Mbytes per second
ftp: 265174 bytes sent in 0.07Seconds 3682.97Kbytes/sec.
Error opening local file javascripts.
Error opening local file stylesheets.
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 57129
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.033 seconds (measured here), 36.90 Kbytes per second
ftp: 1229 bytes sent in 0.01Seconds 102.42Kbytes/sec.
ftp> quit
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 261 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

None of the files are folders inside the build folder are in use when I run the .bat file, I'm a bit stumped why none of the folders are being uploaded. I've tried replacing `bin` with `ascii` but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows command-line `ftp.exe` client does not support recursive operations.

You have to use a 3rd-party FTP client.

---

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) you can use:

```
winscp.com /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "mput ""%2\*"" ""%1""" ^
    "exit"
```

There's a guide for [converting Windows `ftp.exe` script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp). Though easier is to have [WinSCP GUI generate the script or batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*